# Supressing PDB generation from the command line - C++

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-options

I've had a search around and can find a few examples of using Visual Studio menus to suppress creation of PDB files. I need to do this for a project I'm building, however, this requires using the Visual Studio compiler from the command line only. Is there a command line switch for disabling PDB generation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate through project settings in Visual Studio, most options tell you what their equivalent command-line switch is.

To disable link-time PDB generation, omit the `/DEBUG` switch.

To disable compile-time PDB generation, omit the `/Z` switch (`/Z{7|i|I}`).

[Edit] Oh, in fact if you use the `/Z7` switch, the debug information is generated into the object file instead of a PDB.  So that particular one is okay.  Compilation is faster without it, however.  So omit if you don't want any debug information.