# Disable C++ PDB generation from the IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, pdb-files

We need to surpress generation of debug symbols. The options availble under project properties/ configuration properties / c/c++ / general / debug information format, are equivalent to /Z7, /Zi and /ZI - I can't find a way to omit the /Zx flag entirely.

Unlike [the situation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944768/supressing-pdb-generation-from-the-command-line-c) - we're building from the IDE.

I'm using visual studio 2010, and the project at hand is a static library.

EDIT:
Here's the view from my installation of VS2012. Is this some installation issue?? Are your Debug-Information-Format options different?
[image]

Comment: I don't get this question.  You already found the "Debug Information Format" option in the IDE, why don't you set it to "Disabled"?

Comment: My IDEs (VS2010/2012) don't have a 'disabled' option under Debug Information Format. Do you see one?

Comment: Well, that's bizarre.  Options in the dropdown list, in order, for VS2008 are Disabled, C7 Compatible, Program database, Program database for Edit & Continue.  In VS2012 the first one is renamed to None.  Don't have VS2010 anymore to check.

Comment: Hans: please not the addition to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can remove it manually:

### Step 1. Compiler.

- Selected "Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Debug Information Format"
- Hit <kbd>DEL</kbd>

[image]

### Step 2. Linker.

Also you need to disable generating Debug info for Linker

- Selected "Configuration Properties > Linker > Debugging> Generate Debug Info" set to **No**

[image]

### Step 3. Profiler.

- Also set **"Profile"** to **"No"** in Linker > Advanced or you may still see PDB files generated!

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp is that .net C++ version? I've never used it, to be honest. I've used .net or native C++ (but not C++/CLI). In both cases, there was an option to disabe this. It may be called slightly differently.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first - this is **not** recommended to disable `.PDB` generation, even for a Release Build!

Anyway, you just need to go:

- **Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info**, and set it to `No`

Comment: thanks. Trust me, I'm fully aware of the importance of PDB's, and still I need to disable their generation.  As noted in the question I need to disable generation for a static library - which does not undergo linkage. I.e., I need to disable it at the compiler level - so this solution doesn't hold.